# Make single file with7zip SFX with java jar

Tags: java, jar, 7zip, sfx

Using this tutorial:
http://mark.koli.ch/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx

I'm trying to put the jre and my .jar together,to result of a single executable file, so the JRE will not be required to launch my application.

I use Eclipse to export my project into an executable app.jar file. (file - export - jar, executable jar). Then, I zip the jre and app.jar together:

```
app.7z:
    - jre folder
    - app.jar
```

My app.tag contains this:

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
Title="7ZIP Java Launcher Example"
ExtractDialogText="Extracting ..."
GUIFlags="32"
ExtractTitle="Extracting"
FinishMessage="Application stopped."
RunProgram="jre\bin\javaw.exe -jar app.jar \"%%S\" \"%%T\""
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

Then, I put app.tag, app.7z and 7zSD.sfx into the same folder and use this command line:

```
C:\> copy /b 7zSD.sfx + app.tag + app.7z start.exe
```

The file start.exe is created. When I open it, it says "extracting...", but will always launch "Application stopped".
I have no clue why this happens. I checked into the TEMP of Windows folder, and everything is extracted correctly.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
The .jar itself will open normally when I double-click on it.

Thank you!

Comment: Was this problem ever resolved? Would be good to know before taking the time to try the approach.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to get the **7zSD.sfx** from a previous 7-Zip extra package.

http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z920_extra.7z